# OVR not initializing

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, plugins, oculus

I am trying to upgrade a Unity plugin from 2017.2 to 2019.1.5. The Unity plugin has a backend API that uses the Oculus Native SDK and has it included as external dependencies. When upgrading my Unity version it forced me to upgrade the version of the OVR plugin used by Unity as I was getting errors. I did that and a feature of the plugin is no longer working. I debugged my C++ dll and it appears that OVR is not initializing in the API. I get error code -1004, ovrError_NotInitialized.
I tried upgrading the version of the OVR SDK used by the API from 1.19.0 to 1.37.0 but it still doesn't work. It's possible I did something wrong as I wasn't the original person who set this up and I am way more experienced with Unity and C# than C++ and having external files. Unity 2019.1.5 is currently using the 1.37.0 version of the OVR Utilities Plugin. Thanks. Any and all help is appreciated.
Here is the code that initializes it in the API:

```
           if (OVR_SUCCESS(status)) {
               g_ovrInitialized = true;
           } else {
               ovrErrorInfo info;
               ovr_GetLastErrorInfo(&info);
               cout << "ovr_Initialize() failed! " << info.ErrorString << endl;
           }
```

I tried the OculusTinyRoom(DX12) sample that uses the Oculus Rift native C++ SDK and I was able to get it working. I, however, tried another sample, the GuardianRoomDemo, and it does not work. I can see the process for it in the task manager but it never opens. The one that does not open attempts to initialize the rift the same way the API does, with a null pointer passed to the ovr_Initialize function. I am not however able to check if the initialization is failing for the GuardianRoomDemo because it tries to initialize as soon as the application is opened so I can't just attach the debugger to the process and see what is going on, unfortunately.

Comment: Sounds difficult! Is it at all possible that there's a racing situation occuring in the loading process, and that now OVR initialization simply takes longer, and the C++ externality wants to rely on it without waiting long enough in the startup sequence?

Comment: Afaik Unity 2017 and 2019 use completely different OVR libraries. In 2019 it is now a package (`OpenVR(Dekstop)`, `Oculus Desktop` and `Oculus Android`) in the PackageManager and might work different then the former SDK untiypackage....